# Custom Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract calculate twice: billing&shipping address

Tags: magento, module, checkout, e-commerce

I intended to make a custom credit module which can use our store's credits for discount. After looking into some examples, I successfully added a checkout step to the onepage checkout. And then I extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract to have a custom collector to calculate total. Currently I hard coded some discount value to see how it works:

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        parent::collect ( $address );
        //if($address->getData('address_type')=='billing') return $this;

        try {

            $this->_setAmount ( -10 )->_setBaseAmount ( -10 );

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            Mage::throwException ( $e->getMessage () );

        //do nothing.    
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        parent::fetch ( $address );
        //if($address->getData('address_type')=='billing') return $this;
        $title = Mage::helper ( 'sales' )->__ ( 'Credittest' );
        $address->addTotal ( array ('code' => $this->getCode (), 'title' => $title, 'value' => -10 ) );
        return $this;
    }
```

The section in config.xml looks like this:

```
<sales>
    <quote>
        <totals>
            <credittest>
                 <class>sales/quote_address_total_credit</class>
                 <after>tax_subtotal,subtotal,freeshipping</after>
                 <before>grand_total</before>
            </credittest>
        </totals>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

However the result comes out with -20 deducted. after some debug tracing, my custom collector are called twice, once the address type is "billing" and another is "shipping". So I added the commented code above to calculate only when shipping address comes in. But i'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Why other class in  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address won't calculate twice? They are actually invoked twice according to my tracing. And what's right way solve my issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento Add Fee or Discount to Order Totals](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total)